# Is there a way to get the stage from from a FXML controller?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a window that has 2 scenes that i need to change between when i click a button. I am having issues trying to think of ways to efficiently change scenes from the controller for the FXML document. Is there a method to do this with javafx like this.getScene().getStage() or something along those lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller has most likely access to a Node (eg Button) the you can do

```
@FXML
Button b;
...
@FXML
public void flip() {
  Stage s = (Stage)b.getScene().getWindow();
}
```