# Eclipse RCP 4 + JavaFX - How to load Scene saved as FXML

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, rcp

I want to switch my Eclipse RCP 3.x based on SWT application to Eclipse RCP 4.x and JavaFX but I struggle throught magical @statements and... JavaFx in Eclipse RCP.

The problem I have is to switch from one FX scene to another. I cant figure it out how to get JavaFX primary stage, the code:

```
private void load()
{
    try {
    Stage primaryStage = Facade.PrimaryStage;
    StackPane page = (StackPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(_fxmlPath));
    Scene scene = new Scene(page);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("FXML is Simple");
    primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any working example how to initialize variable:

```
Stage primaryStage
```

Or maybe there is any other way to switch FX scenes?

As there are not so many examples how to use JavaFX in Eclipse RCP 4.x (I feel that non of these even works with newest Eclipse SDK + JavaFX), is this environment good to switch from Eclipse RCP 3.x or is it just "proff of concept"?

Answer (score 1):

e4 on JavaFX is in production ready but i'm not sure what you want to achieve! Did you look at the samples at - see https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials

Comment: yes I did, I have the sample project from Tutorial nr 3 in my Eclipse IDE but my project consists of more than one view/scene so that I need to switch scenes (and persist all the controls in memory in case someone will switch it back). Could you provide any example how to switch and if it is possible to load FXML file as scene somehow?

Comment: Ok, I have primary stage of JavaFx 
(You answered on similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033363/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-stage-from-from-a-fxml-controller/38033408#38033408), but still dont know how to resolve the path to FXML in Eclipse RCP:

FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(_fxmlPath))

Comment: well - i repeat that I don't think there is a need to switch the scene content at all anyways loading of fxml in osgi is bit tricky - https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Runtime/Recipes#.40FXMLLoader - the code above uses a path relative to the getClass() so without knowing your project layout and the content of _fxmlPath we can't help

Comment: Hmm... ok so in Eclipse RCP 3.x I have those "views" as perspectives then I simply switch perspectives. Can I do the same in JavaFx and EclipseRCP 4.x?

Comment: Sure just create perspectives in the e4xmi file and use EPartService to switch

Comment: as You are expert from Eclipse RCP 4.x I have one more question related to topic... as you said that loading FXML file is not recommended, is there any recommended "WYSIWYG way" to create views? maybe using JavaFx Scene Builder? the question is actually about good practice of creating JavaFx view using Eclipse 4.x

Comment: And do the JavaFx transitions works in EclipseRCP application? As it is one of the reason I want to move my project

Comment: Yes you can use transitions to switch from perspective to perspective - there's a special service in e4 on JavaFX

Comment: I never said that useing FXML is wrong - I only said it's tricky - I use both in my applications pure java and fxml

Answer (score 0):

Ok actually I have found the solution:

1. Create a Part in Application.e4xmi
2. Add to the Part the code below which fill it by JavaFx controls from *.fxml:

   ```
   @PostConstruct
   void init(@org.eclipse.fx.ui.di.FXMLLoader FXMLLoaderFactory pFactory, BorderPane pPane, MPart pPart) {
   try
   {
       FXMLBuilder<Node> lBuilder = pFactory.loadRequestorRelative("/scenes/SceneA.fxml");
       _mainControl = lBuilder.load();
       pPane.setCenter(_mainControl);
   }catch(Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   }

(*dont forget to add folder with all the *.fxml files to META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as You will be surpreised by errors when You will try to create the app export/build)